# Разбиение кода на функции

Tags: code-style

Как вы код разбиваете на функции? В книжке читал что тело функции должно умещаться в один экран и стараюсь придерживаться этого правила. Правильно ли это?

Comment: да, это правильно. А какие у вас основания в этом сомневаться?

Comment: я код на функции логически разбиваю(если вообще можно так выразиться).  а критерий сомнительный, вот в книжке наверняка имелся ввиду экран редактора в консоли 80x25, т.е. тело функции не больше 25ти строк, реально, но придерживаетесь ли вы этого ? И как избегаете спагетти ?

Comment: ну есть у меня такое мнение что функция должна завершать код логически. то есть расматриватся как логически завершонная задача и поэтому бывает зачастую выхожу за рамки одного экрана.

Comment: @DreamChild Один экран -- это сколько (один знакомый устанавливал очень мелкий шрифт на 1280х1024)?

Язык? Одно дело -- ассемблер, другое -- C++/Java (про Haskell и вспоминать не будем)

Главное -- чтобы читать было удобно. Жёстких стандартов нет и быть не может.

Comment: речь, понятно, идет не об ассемблере (во всяком случае, эта знаменитая рекомендация предполагает написание на более высокоуровневом языкеб условно говря, Java или какой-нибудь C#) Ну и "один экран" - выражение не совсем корректное, хотя и устоявшееся. Обычно под "одним экраном" подразумевают, что функция должна быть не более 25-50 строк

Comment: Функция должна быть завершенной логической единицей программы. Она должна делать что-то одно и делать это четко и ясно и при этом быть защищенной от ошибок и протестированной. Следствием этого и является ее маленький размер. А правило  что вы приводите весьма паршиво хотя бы потому что существуют много разных разрешений экрана.

Comment: > да, это правильно

Ага, и на каждый экран по строке комментариев обязательно надо. Бред из той же серии. Надо по возможности писать код так, чтобы его было удобно читать и модифицировать.

Comment: @Flammable полагаете, что читать и модифицировать поток сознания из пяти сотен строк легко и удобно? Если так любите придираться к словам, то, пожалуйста, учтите, что это правило является не более чем эмпирическим, то есть основанным на опыте энного количества разработчиков, и даже более того, не является ни обязательным к исполнению, ни даже правилом вообще, а всего лишь рекомендацией, или даже индикатором, который может сообщить, что если у вас весь код состоит из таких "потоков сознания" в 500 строк, то нужно крепко задуматься на тему рефакторинга.

Comment: > полагаете, что читать и модифицировать поток сознания из пяти сотен строк легко и удобно?

Почему 500, а не 5000? Чего это вас в крайности бросает? Я вовсе не придираюсь к словам. Потом всякие менеджеры насаждают эти "эмпирические правила" везде, где могут: длина функции не более 100 строк, количество аргументов не более 3, goto использовать нельзя и прочее. И считают, что этим они способствуют написанию хорошего кода.

Comment: >Почему 500, а не 5000?

Если угодно, подставьте сюда любое другое достаточно большое число. Вы не видите в этом одной очевидной вещи, о которой я уже писал - "один экран" - это не самоцель и не жесткое правило, согласно которому следует тут же обрезать все свои функции. Хотите поспорить на эту тему? Отлично, напишите гневное письмо г-ну Фаулеру, автору той гадской книжки про рефакторинг и обвините его в незнании матчасти, заодно и про goto упомяните. Вероятно, в следующем издании своей книги он запишет вас в число соавторов, а то и вовсе устыдится и не станет выпускать ее.

Comment: > Вы не видите в этом одной очевидной вещи, о которой я уже писал - "один экран" - это не самоцель и не жесткое правило
Дело в том, что некоторые программеры вместо того, чтобы писать код, открывают эмпирические правила. Потом появляются книжки, где такие правила преподносятся категорично. Функции небольшого размера - это, конечно, хорошо. Но это возможно далеко не всегда.

Comment: @Flammable догматика из серии "заставь дурака Богу молиться"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Отвечу несколько более развернуто. 
Компилятору в принципе, совершенно плевать на размеры ваших функций/методов/всего остального - ему важно лишь отсутствие в нем синтаксических ошибок. То есть размер функции "в один экран" - это лишь удобство для самого разработчика и для тех, кто в последствии будет иметь счастье (или несчастье) это читать и сопровождать. Есть пример из собственного опыта - та система, что я пишу/сопровождаю на работе, писалась несколько лет тому назад не очень опытным программистом, отчего сейчас она изобилует огромными километровыми портянками кода, который на протяжении всех этих километров усердно сам себя повторяет и содержит всяческое непотребство наподобие таких вот идентификаторов:  db_some_important_class_from_db_for_updating_this_table. Более того, методы классов, которыми заполнен этот всесторонне замечательный код, имеют дикие размеры в 1-2 тысячи строк, и выполняют все на свете - получение данных из GUI, выполнение какой-то бизнес-логики, запись в базу данных и много-премного всяческих других действий. Так вот работать с этим очень тяжело ии чревато  множеством ошибок. Код словно по волшебству становится связанным миллионом отношений, которые находятся в очень хрупком взаимодействии, и элементарные изменения могут порушить все эти связи к чертовой матери, что неоднократно и случалось - после, казалось бы, совершенно безобидного изменения логики рушилась половина функциональности приложения. 
   Так или иначе, из вышесказанного вытекает нижеследующее (мораль, так сказать):

В подавляющем большинстве случаев для выполнения какой-либо задачи достаточно функций указанного размера. В противном случае нужно либо пересмотреть свой стиль кодирования и сделать его более лаконичным, либо разбить задачу на ряд меньших - еще раз повторюсь, как из собственного опыта, так и из опыта других, куда более компетентных людей, могу сказать, что если вам кажется, что соблюсти это правило невозможно, то, скорее всего, вам это лишь кажется. 
Ну и напоследок почитайте вот [это](http://habrahabr.ru/post/166113/)

Comment: внутри метода класса то же код разбивать надо

Comment: а вот в этом вам поможет вот эта http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/1308678/ без преувеличения прекрасная книга

Comment: Я уже приводил цитату из эссе пионера веб-программирования П. Грэма, что ООП -- это крэк для тех, кто в старые времена писал функции длиной в страницу распечатки: 5-10 строк кода, остальное -- комментарии.

Comment: +1, хорошее объяснение.

Comment: @DreamChild, мдэ, если это действительно так, то вам "повезло" с сопровождением кода неопытного программёра =)

Comment: @good, если уж на то пошло, то в ООП "это" называется не функциями, а методами класса. А уже между этими двумя понятиями существует несколько серьезных отличий.

Comment: к сожалению, "повезло". В последнее время я этим занимаюсь чуть меньше, но полгода-год тому назад мне часто приходилось в этом всем ковыряться, причем, человек, его писавший, был моим непосредственным руководителем, и сам неоднократно признавал, что код ужасен

Comment: @DreamChild: а переписать с нуля не вариант? Или хоть выбить две-три недели на подробный рефакторинг.

Comment: @DreamChild ну значит Вам ещё повезло. Хуже, если бы автор считал, что его код вполне "на уровне"

Comment: бизнес, к сожалению, не ждет. За переписывание с нуля высказывался не я один, но на это нужно время и/или энное количество дополнительных программистов.  Ни того, ни другого не дают. Время от времени пытаюсь выполнять точечный рефакторинг, но его тоже приходится делать очень осторожно - не раз бывали случаи, когда после безобидных, казалось бы, улучшений/изменений отказывали ранее хорошо работавшие элементы всей системы.

Comment: > ну значит Вам ещё повезло

да, именно -  как менеджер (да и с точки зрения человеческих качеств) это очень и очень адекватный и грамотный человек, а программированием он уже довольно давно не занимается, так что не все так печально, как могло бы быть)

Comment: Да, я когда-то тоже видел программу (еще на PL/I) из пары тысяч строк и почти без функций. 

Такаааяяяя портянка. Ее многие помогали автору отладить, но (насколько помню) без особого успеха. Как говорится "хвост вытащил, нос увяз".

А если серьезно, то все правильно, логически независимая часть программы почти всегда укладывается в пару-тройку десятков строк.

Бывают, конечно исключения, когда эти части связаны по большому количеству общих данных и **выполняются однократно и последовательно**. Иногда просто рука не поднимается выделить их в функции, а данные объединить в структуру.